# BinarySearch gives an erroe type "Collections is not applicable for the arguments"

Tags: java, collections, binary-search

i am new to java and encountering a problem with Collections.binarySearch, i have raed the javadoc and check lots of answers in here, but still dealing with a problem. before the actual code, a background:
i am writing a code that lets the user manage a contact book.
this is my Contact class

```
public class Contact implements Comparable<Contact>  {
private String name;
private String email;
private String phone;
private String address;
```

i have a comparator

```
public int compareTo(Contact contact) {  
    return name.compareToIgnoreCase(contact.getName());  
}
```

also inside the class, and i have a different class for the copmare itself

```
public class ContactComparator implements Comparator<Contact> {
@Override
public int compare(Contact first, Contact second) {
  String one = first.getName();
  String two = second.getName();
  int f = one.compareToIgnoreCase(two);
  return f;
}
```

}

in the code i've sort my list all the time, like someone here helped me before

```
Collections.sort(contacts , new ContactComparator())
```

now my problem is that im trying to use binary search in a search method that goes like:

```
public int ContactIndex(final String name){
    return Collections.binarySearch(contacts, name, new ContactComparator());  
}
```

but it gives me this error:

> The method binarySearch(List, T, Comparator) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList, String, ContactComparator)

i need your help again guys, thank you all helpers!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send a `Contact` as argument that contains the `name` of the desired contact to search instead of sending just a `String`. Note that your `ContactComparator` compares `Contact`s not `Contact` and `String`.

The code would look like this:

```
public int ContactIndex(final String name) {
    Contact contactToSearch = new Contact();
    contactToSearch.setName(name);
    return Collections.binarySearch(contacts, contactToSearch, new ContactComparator());  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Method signature is

```
public static <T> int binarySearch(List<? extends T> list, T key, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Your T is `String`. So your List must contain a subclass of String. Same goes with the Comparator. Now your `Contact class does not extend String`.. so you are getting the error.